# how to search one country by name from the REST countries api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await, fetch-api

I need to use async await + fetch for REST countries API for 2 purposes:

1)Click on "show all countries" which draws all countries (which works!)

2)Click on "search by name" after the user had input and fetch that single country<-- this one I can't succeed...it's quite confusing because I MUST use jquery for everything than the requests. I'll paste my code and hope anyone can help me , I'm desperate!

```js
$("button").click(function() {
 $("#display").empty();
 getCountries()
 .then(result =>{
  result.forEach(element => {
   var card = $('<div>', {class: "card"}).appendTo('#display');
   var country = $('<div>', {class: "country-info"}).appendTo(card);
   var img = $('<div>', {class: "img"}).appendTo(country);
   $('<img>', {src: element.flag}).appendTo(img);
   var text = $('<div>', {class: "right-text"}).appendTo(country);
   $('<p>', {text: "Name: " + element.name}).appendTo(text);
   $('<p>', {text: "Top Level Domain: " + element.topLevelDomain}).appendTo(text);
   $('<p>', {text: "Capital: " + element.capital}).appendTo(text);
   $('<h4>', {text: 'Currencies:'}).appendTo(text);
   element.currencies.forEach(element =>{
    var currencies = $('<div>', {
     class: "currencies"
    }).appendTo(text);
    $('<span>', {text: element.code + " "}).appendTo(currencies);
   })
  });
  
 })
 .catch(err =>console.log(err));
});


async function getCountries(){
 const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`);
 const responseData = await response.json();

 return responseData;
}

async function getCountryName(){
 const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/`);
 const responseData = await response.json();

 return responseData;
}
```

```css
img {
 width: 100%;
}
.img {
 width: 30%;
}
.country-info {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<h1 class="text-muted text-center"> Countries of the World</h1>
<div class="container">
 <form>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
   <label for="name">Enter country</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="search" name="name">
   <br/>
   <input class="form-control" type="submit" id="search" value="Search by Name">
  </div>
 </form>
 <button id="show" class="btn btn-success form-control">Show All</button>
 <div id="display" class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

The issue here is unlike your first get request this requires some input from the user -> hence the form... You have to capture their input on submit and append it to the searchURL -> so if they enter Spain your final url ends up as `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/Spain` etc etc...

Basically, you need to research how to handle form submission... You can try and dissect and understand the code I've provided below...

At the moment it's just console.loging not returning and appending the data to the DOM but it should be good enough to get you going in the right direction...

```js
const searchURL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/';

async function getCountryName(name) {
  const url = searchURL + name;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const responseData = await response.json();

  console.log(responseData);
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = $('#js-search-term').val();
    getCountryName(searchTerm);
  });
}

$(watchForm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="text-muted text-center">Countries of the World</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="js-form">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
          <label for="name">Enter country</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="search" name="search-term" id="js-search-term" /> <br />
          <input
            class="form-control"
            type="submit"
            id="search"
            value="Search by Name"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
      <button id="show" class="btn btn-success form-control">Show All</button>
      <div id="display" class="col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , I know what I need  to do theoretically , but I don't know how to catch the value and make the input country drawn , meaning to build the method to search one country to work with jquery ,i'm new to this library , hoped for continuous code...tx anyway, hope someone can help me .

Comment: The code I provided does exactly what you're asking for... It just console.logs the data... All you need to do now is instead of clonsole.loging the data return it and append it to the DOM like you did for the first one...

Comment: Hey ! The code is great , now it is working! there's a bug although , when searching for one country and doing a new search , it keeps adding countries to the screen , how do I delete the previous search so each time there will be only 1 country displaying ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 $("#display").empty();
let name =  e.currentTarget.name.value;
if(!name){

alert("Enter name");

return;
}
 getCountryName(name)
 .then(result =>{
  result.forEach(element => {
   var card = $('<div>', {class: "card"}).appendTo('#display');
   var country = $('<div>', {class: "country-info"}).appendTo(card);
   var img = $('<div>', {class: "img"}).appendTo(country);
   $('<img>', {src: element.flag}).appendTo(img);
   var text = $('<div>', {class: "right-text"}).appendTo(country);
   $('<p>', {text: "Name: " + element.name}).appendTo(text);
   $('<p>', {text: "Top Level Domain: " + element.topLevelDomain}).appendTo(text);
   $('<p>', {text: "Capital: " + element.capital}).appendTo(text);
   $('<h4>', {text: 'Currencies:'}).appendTo(text);
   element.currencies.forEach(element =>{
    var currencies = $('<div>', {
     class: "currencies"
    }).appendTo(text);
    $('<span>', {text: element.code + " "}).appendTo(currencies);
   })
  });
  
 })
 .catch(err =>console.log(err));
});

async function getCountries(){
 const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`);
 const responseData = await response.json();

 return responseData;
}

async function getCountryName(name){
 const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}`);
 const responseData = await response.json();
debugger
 return responseData;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<h1 class="text-muted text-center"> Countries of the World</h1>
<div class="container">
 <form>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
   <label for="name">Enter country</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="search" name="name">
   <br/>
   <input class="form-control" type="submit" id="search" value="Search by Name">
  </div>
 </form>
 <button id="show" class="btn btn-success form-control">Show All</button>
 <div id="display" class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```